# Quando usare molto o tanto

Tags: difference, adverbs

Qual è la differenza tra 'molto' e 'tanto'? Per esempio è corretto dire 'Ho avuto tanto tempo per fare qualcosa' o 'Ho avuto molto tempo per fare qualcosa'?

Comment: “Ho avuto tanto/molto tempo da fare qualcosa” non significa niente. Intendi “...per fare qualcosa”?

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: Grazie DaG e Charo. Charo, sono inglese (mezzo italiano) e come lei io non uso di Windows. Ubuntu è la via da seguire.

Comment: Solitamente qui [ci diamo del tu](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9/ci-diamo-del-tu). Ho corretto le tue frasi come ha indicato @DaG: è questo quello che intendi?

Comment: Charo grazie è questo la cosa che intendevo.

Comment: Nelle tue frasi (tutte e due corrette),  "molto" e "tanto" sono aggettivi e non avverbi.

Comment: Penso che le due frasi abbiano un significato molto simile ma, in alcuni contesti, la frase con "tanto" può avere una sfumatura di "eccessività" (c'era troppo tempo) che non ha la frase con "molto".

Answer (score 4):

La differenza principale è che mentre “molto” significa semplicemente “in gran quantità”, “[tanto](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tanto/)” si può parafrasare con “in *così* gran quantità” e richiede, esplicitamente o implicitamente, una [proposizione consecutiva](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/proposizioni-consecutive_(La-grammatica-italiana)/): per esempio, “Ho avuto tanto tempo per fare qualcosa (che alla fine mi annoiavo)”.

Quindi, anche se lo si usa da solo, mantiene (come accennato giustamente in un commento) un senso di eccesso, di abbondanza.

Answer (score 0):

Native speaker here...

Well, you can say it in both ways.. In Italian saying 
"Ho avuto tanto tempo per..." 
It's grammatically correct but the second one ( "Ho avuto molto tempo per..." ) is more polite...

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I remember the difference:

She has many cats. **Molto**
She has a ton of cats. **Tanto**

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! As a native speaker I don't agree with this distinction.